# Feedback for ESP32-POE board

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design, esp32, poe

just working on an ESP32 board featuring a WROOM32-UE and POE functionality. One of my first PCBs, so I'd appreciate some overall feedback on layout and routing.
**Note that not everything is done yet.** Stackup is 4-layer, with top and bottom signal, GND and 3.3V middle planes. Thick pours for 10W POE are 50mils. Regular traces are 10mil.
[image: POE schematic]
[image: Main schematic]
[image: Routing]

Worried about SI and matched impedance for micro UBS. Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: hi! A four-layer board as first :) nice! Don't get overwhelmed; and don't get frustrated when laying out things – sometimes it happens that you realize that if you put one trace on a different layer, 10 other traces become much shorter, straighter and easier, and then you have to rip things up. That happens!

Comment: So, quick feedback: your decoupling capacitors C16, C26…C29 should be directly connected to your IC, not through traces that change the layer multiple times. That means you should probably re-do that section. However, that's easy, because the lines that you're crossing could easily go to a different layer right at U4 – they connect to through-holes, which cross at every layer, anyways :)

Comment: Looks like the high speed differential pairs are not wired as high speed differential pairs but as random wires. If you worry about matched impedance, you should then wire these as differential pairs and with correct impedance.

Comment: R18, R28 are placed 1. unnecessarily in a region that's already far too crowded for easy placing of components (should you plan to do this by hand), and 2. not logically at all – they are connected to the ethernet Jack at the **opposite** part of U4. So, you will have to move them completely. At this point: full re-layout of the components and connections between RJ11, U4 and U6.  That's a good thing – your board is super tight and crowded in the rigth half, and quite empty on the left. Take this chance to move U2 to the free space, (maybe rotate H2 and move it a bit to the board edge?),

Comment: put SW2 and SW1 close to the board edge, where a human finger can actually press them. Rotate U6 by 90°, move it to the left . Make sure you know where the coax connector on U6 is, and whether the coax cable you connect to that needs some free board space so you can actually press it onto the connector! Place all the decoupling capacitors close (adjacent!) to the supply pins they belong to, connect them first. Then follow the guidance from U6 module documentation and U4's docs on the high-speed signals

Comment: Generally, this all reminds me of my first PCBs – I was a student, and thought saving 3€ on board space was a good idea. It was not. If your application allows, make this prototype maybe twice as large – your layouting will suddenly become much easier. Shrinking later is easy once you know things work. Speaking of knowing that things work: you do have testpoints on what I presume is a UART line between U2 and U6, right, so you can see what happens with a cheap USB-serial adapter, and program U6 without going through U2, should the upbring of that take longer than expected?

Comment: What is the purpose of FETs on USB data pins, what is that supposed to achieve? The MDI TX and RX terminations are connected to same common mode node, I don't think that is intended usage.

Comment: Also, a bit confused about C25: I understand the R16, R17 pair (and R20, R21) as differential termination of the MDI pair. C25 looks like a short to high frequencies, but isolates DC from GND, so that makes sense (though I'm a bit surprised this would be necessary on the same board) I'm a bit confused that you're coupling both MDI pairs through the same C25 – if C25 is necessary to avoid DC currents, then you would not want these two flow between the two MDI pairs, instead, would you?